# How to add event rates at the end of the Kaplan Meier curves i.e. at 3 years

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survminer

I need to add event rates at the end of the Kaplan Meier curves i.e. at 3 years.

Here is a sample database and my code

```
library(ggsurvfit);library(ggplot2); library(survival); library(survminer)

BMT<-data(BMT)
fit <- survfit(Surv(ftime/12, status >0)~ dis, data= BMT)   
summary(fit,times=c(1,2,3))
a<-ggsurvplot(fit, fun=  "event",  
              xlim = c(0,3),
              xlab="Time (Months)",#axes.offset = F,
              break.x.by =0.5,#xscale = "d_m",
              ylim=c(0,0.90),  
              ylab="Primary outcome (%)",   risk.table = T, #  
              risk.table.col = "strata", 
              risk.table.pos="out",
              risk.table.y.text = F,  
              legend=c(0.15,0.8),
              #legend=c(0,1),
              cumevents=F,
              cumevents.title   ="Cumulative events",
              cumevents.col ="strata",
              cumevents.y.text=F,censor=F,  
              legend.labs = c("No","Yes"),
              legend.title = "Diseased", conf.int = F, conf.int.style = "ribbon", 
              pval = F,   pval.coord = c(2,0.2), tables.height = 0.2,
              tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
              data = BMT,  palette =  c("blue4","red4") );a

### Change y axis to be in percent
a$plot<-a$plot+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.9),
                                  breaks = seq(0,0.9,by=0.1), labels = seq(0,90,by=10))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3), labels = c(0,6,12,18,24,30,36));a
```

I expect the output to be like this

[image]
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by event rates? do you need the percent who didn't have the event at 3 years?

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your comment. I mean the percent of those who had events in each arm beside each curve (aligned at 3 years time-point).

Comment: `geom_text()` or `geom_label()` should be able to help here